# How to change default language (International not programming) in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an android app that is not localized. All my strings are in strings.xml file.

After submitting to the store, I am getting a warning that my apk contains Australian English and I should provide images and the like for it.

I am using Android Studio 3.3.1 on Windows 10, and the OS language is English US. I don't know where is Australian English coming from, I am not even in Australia!

Where can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a response from Google Store support.

Apparently, the wording of their warning is a bit misleading. 
They actually wanted to suggest I translate into Australian English, because I have users there.

So, if you get this it's safe to ignore...

Answer (score 0):

Click on Default (en-us)
which have list as per your string file added 
for more you need to add string file

/values-es

/value-gu

it means you have options
1 for gu 
2 for es
[image]

Comment: I've checked each activity and they are all set to en-US. No Australia anywhere.